# Can I enclose a tomb with constructed walls in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am trying to build tombs

[image]

In between the second and third doors, the wall was removed to recover gems. I then constructed a wall via the build menu to replace it. This created 2 columns (the two `O` glyphs between two `0` coffins).

The rightmost chamber is already a tomb.

[image]

If I go to Zone > Tomb > Multi and try to enclose the two rightmost rooms it fails with

```
Coffin rejected (not enclosed).
```

Is there a way to build an enclosure which will allow me to make these into tombs?

Answer (score 15):

That smoothed/built wall formation shouldn't result in 2 columns; it should be a continuous wall. Are you sure the wall that you built is in fact built? If that wall is still in the blueprint/pending stage, this behavior would be expected for both walls and tomb designations.

Comment: This is definitely the problem: the northern constructed wall is still being built, which is why it's displayed in reversed color.